# checking the calendar but doesn't work

Tags: android

I try to check the calendar when evey first day of each month will auto send data but the problem code doesn't work.

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
if (Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH == 25){
sendMessage("L100000000");}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need this

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
int dayOfMonth = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

if (dayOfMonth == 25){
    sendMessage("L100000000");
}
```

Comment: thank. i donot have any experience in develop android, how can i make this function auto run when the apps is connect to other device?